# Authenticate with API key

Tags: python, artifactory

I am using the artifactory python module, and my repo does not allow anonymous login, so I need to log in.

The first attempt was with the username and password; although I do not want to include that in the code; so I was looking at how to use the API key from my server.

The documentation does not seem to include any option for using the artifactory API key. Is there a way to generate a connection with artifactory, using the key, and then use the artifactory python module?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `python-requests` module to access the artifactory api.

**Ex:**

```
import requests
requests.get(url, headers={"X-JFrog-Art-Api": yourArtifactoryKey })
```

Comment: I see, so you use directly the REST API with request library, instead of use the artifactory library? Also can I pass the parameter as `username:KEY` or do I have to pass it as header parameter? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the possible authentication methods in the REST API wiki page:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-Authentication

API Key can be used as password in basic authentication, as well as using the "X-JFrog-Art-Api" dedicated header.